# java svnkit: read content of file directly from repository, without exporting it

Tags: java, svn, svnkit

I am using svnkit in Java to interact with a svn repository.

I would like to read the content of a file that is stored in svn without checking it out from the repository or exporting it. Is that possible?

Example filename that i would like to read:
http://svnserver/myproject/example.txt

Can you help me out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [SVNRepository.getFile(String path, long revision, SVNProperties properties, OutputStream contents)](http://svnkit.com/javadoc/org/tmatesoft/svn/core/io/SVNRepository.html#getFile%28java.lang.String,%20long,%20org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNProperties,%20java.io.OutputStream%29).

Comment: Thanks a lot .. it is amazing!! +1