# How to convert string into formfile

Tags: java

Is there any way to convert a `string` into `formfile` in `Java`?

I am stuck here:

```
fos.write(file.getFileData());
```

Instead of a `file` I am having a `string` and I cannot use `getFileData()` for a `string`.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What you want to do after converting it into `formfile`?

Answer (score 2):

This formfile data type is inbuilt in struts framework. 
So in file upload is the only place you can get the file details like that.

As far as i know,  it is not possible to convert like this.

Comment: didn't solve my question but thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

FromFile's `getFileData()` method returns content in form of bytes.

You can use String's `getBytes()` method here.

Comment: i tried doing that but still it's not unzipping the file

Comment: what exactly you want to do here?

Comment: Actually i am having 2 radio buttons. one is svn path and other is browse. From browse button when i am selecting any zip file its is getting unzipped as per my code but when i give svn path it is not getting unzipped

Comment: so you are passing svn path string here ?

Comment: How can i tell java that its a file and not string

Comment: See you are just passing a string, thats not a  content of file. First you have to get file from svn then you can use that file in your code.

Comment: Following post can help you to get file from SVN using JAVA
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994848/java-svnkit-read-content-of-file-directly-from-repository-without-exporting-it

Answer (score 0):

if that file is present in SVN repository then you need to use `svnkit`.

[you need to use this method](http://svnkit.com/javadoc/org/tmatesoft/svn/core/io/SVNRepository.html#getFile(java.lang.String,%20long,%20org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNProperties,%20java.io.OutputStream))